# Enum to String with Delphi LiveBindings

Tags: delphi, rtti, livebindings

I'm using the RAD Studio LiveBindings demo and have created a TGender Enum for the TPerson, which I want displayed as a string instead in a grid. I'm using the TListBindSourceAdapter as the data is stored in a TObjectList. I have created a TConverterDescription and registered it, but the Enum is still showing up as an integer in the grid. How can this be shown as a string automatically, without adding addition "EnumDescription" or similar fields on the class itself? Sample source code below (based on Delphi samples):

**uMain.pas**

```
unit uMain;

interface

uses
  Spring.Data.ObjectDataSet,
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  Data.Bind.EngExt, Fmx.Bind.DBEngExt, Data.Bind.Components,
  Data.Bind.ObjectScope, CollectionObjects, System.Rtti, Fmx.Bind.Grid,
  System.Bindings.Outputs, Fmx.Bind.Editors, Data.Bind.Grid, FMX.Layouts,
  FMX.Grid, FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls,
  System.Generics.Collections, REST.JSON,
  Data.Bind.GenData, FMX.ScrollBox, FMX.Memo, FMX.TabControl,
  Data.Bind.Controls, Fmx.Bind.Navigator, FMX.Grid.Style, System.JSON, FMX.Memo.Types;

type

  TGender = (Male, Female, NonBinary);

  TPerson = class
  private
    FAge: Integer;
    FLastName: string;
    FFirstName: string;
    FGender: TGender;
  public
    constructor Create(FirstName, LastName: String; Age: Integer; Gender: TGender);
    property FirstName: string read FFirstName write FFirstName;
    property LastName: string read FLastName write FLastName;
    property Age: Integer read FAge write FAge;
    property Gender: TGender read FGender write FGender;
  end;

  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    AdapterBindSource1: TAdapterBindSource;
    BindingsList1: TBindingsList;
    TabControl1: TTabControl;
    GridTab: TTabItem;
    Grid1: TGrid;
    LinkGridToDataSourceAdapterBindSource12: TLinkGridToDataSource;
    DataGeneratorAdapter1: TDataGeneratorAdapter;
    NavigatorAdapterBindSource1: TBindNavigator;
    procedure AdapterBindSource1CreateAdapter(Sender: TObject; var ABindSourceAdapter: TBindSourceAdapter);
  private
    fMyPeople: TObjectList<TPerson>;
    fMyPeopleDB: TObjectDataSet;
  public
  end;

var
  MainForm: TMainForm;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}
{$R *.LgXhdpiPh.fmx ANDROID}
{$R *.iPhone4in.fmx IOS}

constructor TPerson.Create(FirstName, LastName: String; Age: Integer; Gender: TGender);
begin
  FFirstName := FirstName;
  FLastName := LastName;
  FAge := Age;
  FGender := Gender;
end;

procedure TMainForm.AdapterBindSource1CreateAdapter(Sender: TObject;
  var ABindSourceAdapter: TBindSourceAdapter);
begin
  // A collection that owns the TPerson objects
  fMyPeople := TObjectList<TPerson>.Create;

  // The individual TPerson objects
  fMyPeople.Add(TPerson.Create('Gomez', 'Addams', 40, Male));
  fMyPeople.Add(TPerson.Create('Morticia', 'Addams', 38, Female));
  fMyPeople.Add(TPerson.Create('Pugsley', 'Addams', 8, NonBinary));
  fMyPeople.Add(TPerson.Create('Wednesday', 'Addams', 12, NonBinary));

  fMyPeople.Add(TPerson.Create('Uncle', 'Fester', 55, Male));
  fMyPeople.Add(TPerson.Create('Grandmama', 'Frump', 72, Female));
  fMyPeople.Add(TPerson.Create('', 'Lurch', 50, Male));
  fMyPeople.Add(TPerson.Create('Thing T.', 'Thing', 99, NonBinary));
  fMyPeople.Add(TPerson.Create('Cousin', 'Itt', 21, NonBinary));

  // Use TObjectBindSourceAdapter for a single object
  ABindSourceAdapter := TListBindSourceAdapter<TPerson>.Create(Self, fMyPeople, True);
end;

procedure RegisterConverters;
begin
  TValueRefConverterFactory.RegisterConversion(TypeInfo(TGender), TypeInfo(string),
    TConverterDescription.Create(
      procedure(const InValue: TValue; var OutValue: TValue)
      begin
        case InValue.AsType<TGender> of
          Female: OutValue := TValue.From<string>('Female');
          NonBinary: OutValue := TValue.From<string>('Non Binary');
        else
          OutValue := TValue.From<string>('Male');
        end;
      end,
      'TGenderToString', 'TGenderToString', EmptyStr, True, EmptyStr, nil)
  );
end;

initialization
  RegisterConverters;

end.
```

**uMain.fmx**

```
object MainForm: TMainForm
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Adapter Bind Source - Bidirectional object binding'
  ClientHeight = 480
  ClientWidth = 640
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object TabControl1: TTabControl
    Align = Client
    Size.Width = 640.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 480.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabIndex = 0
    TabOrder = 3
    TabPosition = PlatformDefault
    Sizes = (
      640s
      454s)
    object GridTab: TTabItem
      CustomIcon = <
        item
        end>
      IsSelected = True
      Size.Width = 43.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 26.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      StyleLookup = ''
      TabOrder = 0
      Text = 'Grid'
      ExplicitSize.cx = 42.000000000000000000
      ExplicitSize.cy = 26.000000000000000000
      object Grid1: TGrid
        Align = Client
        CanFocus = True
        ClipChildren = True
        Size.Width = 640.000000000000000000
        Size.Height = 429.000000000000000000
        Size.PlatformDefault = False
        TextSettings.Font.Size = 18.000000000000000000
        StyledSettings = [Family, Style, FontColor]
        TabOrder = 1
        RowHeight = 30.000000000000000000
        RowCount = 9
        Viewport.Width = 636.000000000000000000
        Viewport.Height = 404.000000000000000000
      end
      object NavigatorAdapterBindSource1: TBindNavigator
        Align = Top
        Margins.Left = 10.000000000000000000
        Margins.Right = 10.000000000000000000
        Position.X = 10.000000000000000000
        Size.Width = 620.000000000000000000
        Size.Height = 25.000000000000000000
        Size.PlatformDefault = False
        TabOrder = 0
        DataSource = AdapterBindSource1
        VisibleButtons = [nbFirst, nbPrior, nbNext, nbLast, nbInsert, nbDelete, nbEdit, nbPost, nbCancel]
        xRadius = 4.000000000000000000
        yRadius = 4.000000000000000000
        ConfirmDelete = False
      end
    end
  end
  object AdapterBindSource1: TAdapterBindSource
    AutoActivate = True
    OnCreateAdapter = AdapterBindSource1CreateAdapter
    Adapter = DataGeneratorAdapter1
    ScopeMappings = <>
    Left = 368
    Top = 376
  end
  object BindingsList1: TBindingsList
    Methods = <>
    OutputConverters = <>
    Left = 492
    Top = 373
    object LinkGridToDataSourceAdapterBindSource12: TLinkGridToDataSource
      Category = 'Quick Bindings'
      DataSource = AdapterBindSource1
      GridControl = Grid1
      Columns = <
        item
          MemberName = 'FirstName'
          Width = 120
        end
        item
          MemberName = 'LastName'
          Width = 200
        end
        item
          MemberName = 'Age'
          Width = 32
        end
        item
          MemberName = 'Gender'
        end>
    end
  end
  object DataGeneratorAdapter1: TDataGeneratorAdapter
    FieldDefs = <
      item
        Name = 'FirstName'
        Generator = 'LoremIpsum'
        ReadOnly = False
      end
      item
        Name = 'LastName'
        Generator = 'LoremIpsum'
        ReadOnly = False
      end
      item
        Name = 'Age'
        FieldType = ftInteger
        Generator = 'Integers'
        ReadOnly = False
      end
      item
        Name = 'Gender'
        Generator = 'LoremIpsum'
        ReadOnly = False
      end>
    Active = True
    AutoPost = False
    RecordCount = 9
    Options = [loptAllowInsert, loptAllowDelete, loptAllowModify]
    Left = 216
    Top = 376
  end
end
```

Comment: See https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.TypInfo.GetEnumName

Comment: How exactly so you say that helps? I'm not asking how to get the Enum as a string. That's not the issue at hand.